# cannot unpack non-iterable CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail object

Tags: python, django

I am getting the correct computation of quantity and price it shown in my terminal, but when i tried to save it to my database i receive this error **cannot unpack non-iterable CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail object** I have this code in my views.py

```
def addtocart(request):
    userID = request.POST.get("userID")
    client = Customer(id=userID)
    vegetables_id = request.POST.get("id")
    quantity = request.POST.get("quantity")
    percentage = request.POST.get("percentage")
    price = request.POST.get("price")
    v = Product(id=vegetables_id)
    total = float(quantity) * float(price)
    print(total)

    insert, created = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(
        profile=client,
        products = v,
        quantity = quantity,
        unitprice=price,
        discount_percentage = percentage,
        amount = total
    )
    if not created:
        insert.quantity += 1
        insert.save()
```

this is my models.py

```
class CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name="Client Account")

    products = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="Product")
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=1)
    unitquantity = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    totalquantity = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    unitprice = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    discount_percentage = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    discounted_unitprice = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    discounted_amount = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

this is my traceback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\LastProject\OnlinePalengke\customAdmin\views.py" in addtocart
  926.         amount = total

Exception Type: TypeError at /addtocart/
Exception Value: cannot unpack non-iterable CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail object
```

I hope you guys help me with this question, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert, created = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.get_or_create(
        profile=client,
        products = v,
        quantity = quantity,
        unitprice=price,
        discount_percentage = percentage,
        amount = total
    )
    if not created:
        insert.quantity += 1
        insert.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to call the [**`get_or_create()`**--(django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create) method

```
insert, created = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.get_or_create(
        profile=client,
        products = v,
        quantity = quantity,
        unitprice=price,
        discount_percentage = percentage,
        amount = total
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing because it says the error is caused by `amount = total`, but I think the error is actually caused by the ending of the CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail constructor.

```
insert, created = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(
        profile=client,
        products = v,
        quantity = quantity,
        unitprice=price,
        discount_percentage = percentage,
        amount = total
    )
```

so the line causing the error is really more like

```
inserted, created = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(...)
```

CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail calls the **init** function for that class, which I'm assuming is defined in model. **init** always returns the instance of the class called.
However, because you have two variables to the right of the `=`, python is expecting an iterable that returns two values.

And apparently CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail does not fit the bill.